# I get a "please select a value between 8 and 8" when I try to change "Disk space to use" under "Internet Options" in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, internet-explorer

I am running into a strange issue with the Sims 4 video game. The frame rate is in the single digits on my computer when I am connected to the internet, but as soon as I disable the network adapter, frame rate shoots up into the 100s. After doing a lot of digging on the Sims forums, it was suggested to change **Disk space to use** under Control Panel > Network and Internet > Internet Options. When I open that setting window, the value is set to 0, and trying to change is results in the following error

```
Please select a value between 8 and 8 for how much disk space Temporary Internet Files may use.
```

On top of this, the current location settings is empty, and trying to move the folder does nothing.

I can type in the value of 8, and it allows me to `OK` without the error by the value doesn't stick.

Here's a screenshot of the dialog and the error.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same issue due to an incorrect registry setting.

Go to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User
Shell Folders

Change the value for Cache to a location to which I had permission. I believe the default value is %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache

Comment: That actually fixed it. The value was hard coded to a different user's profile.